80s High school boys discover potion of invisibily
This is an 80s movie in a typical high school-environment. 
We meet two friends, who one day invent or discover a potion that can make them invisible. They may have extracted some chemical / slime from a frog in order to do this.
In one scene they walk around the school while invisible, when they suddenly become visible - standing there naked and having to find a place to hide.

Sure it's from the 80s? Reminds me of an old Disney comedy with Kurt Russel. Ah, forget it, Oliver_C's answer sounds more reasonable.

This could be The Invisible Kid (1988):

   [Source]
A nerdy teenage scientist discovers a formula for invisibility, and uses it to take revenge on all those who have wronged him--and also to spy on the girls' shower room.


Watch the trailer

    
    
